# How to handle multiple Webviews issue in android?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-scrollview

I am developing an android application with webviews in my xml page.Here i used 2 webviews in my design page to show different text from links. Here i am getting some flickering(Shaking) in my view when i execute the application in ICS devices. I find the view loading is the problem for flickering of the total view. I want to stop flickering my view. But i dont have any idea how to do that. Please suggest me is there any possibility.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use Intents to handle this issue. In each intent, you can create a client with a fixed URL.

If you have more than a WebView object, is better to create a new Intent to do the transition, so you can avoid potential weird behaviors. Especially in 2.*.

The new Intents also can handle the navigation and web history when tapping the Back button.

Take a look to this URL, in the paragraph 'Handling Page Navigation': http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Comment: Thank you for your response. In my case i should show webview and also my own views like some button and imageviews. need change the button status and imageview status

Answer (score 0):

Hi finally i got solution for my issue multiple webviews in scrollview.I loaded my webview one by one.  Here i use webview client for my first webview. Webview client have two override methods like onPageStarted() and onPageFinished(). i loaded my second webview on onPageFinished() method of 1st webview webclient. Thats all.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
holder.web_view1.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
holder.web_view2.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

to stop flickering